# QGIS layout template with embedded pictures

Tags: qgis, layouts

I have designed different layout templates with a couple of logos (pictures) in QGis 3.12.0, in order to share these with some project partners. The maps can be loaded via PostgreSQL database connection. The problem is that the logo-files (picture.jpeg) are  loeded from my local computer and get lost when the project partners are loading the qps-file or there own local Qgis-project. Is there a way to embedd the pictures in the layout file?

Comment: AFAIK, there isn't any way to embed images into the layout (that aren't already part of the QGIS installation, like the north arrow svgs). You need to send them the qgs file bundled with the images in a location within the project folder, and have the image paths in map layout point to the location using an expression like `@project_folder||'\\images\\name_of_image.jpg'` That way it will look for those images no matter where the project is saved (so no worries if it's C:\Users\You ... or C:\Users\OtherPerson ....)

Comment: I tried but am still not successful. I stored all the files in the project folder c:\project\logos\logo1.jpg. The Qgis project is in the folder project. When I give the file above for image source it works well. What is the correct link for a related file? '\logos\logo1.jpg' or  '\\logos\\logo1.jpg' doesn´t work.

Comment: o.k. i tried a bit mor and found the easy solution...just 'logos/logo1.jpg' worked for me ..thanks!

Answer (score 4):

If you use data URI, you can embed your image into a html frame :

```html
<img width="409" height="53" alt="GIS SE Logo" src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAABPgAAAClCAYAAADBGEOgAAAABHNCSVQICAgIfAhkiAAAAAlwSFlzAAAuIwAALiMBeKU[...]/XpC74hvPwHYtTmYxtNiHNODPP4+d6Yxqsp94bVw9mBpAB0kN+FoC+wVv0AyeMods734217+P8u1hzyOLfc5Hbu/q+59sq8+1ERERERERERGSi+S/RQier1opVngAAAABJRU5ErkJggg==">
```

or use directly the SVG path :

```html
<svg width="409" height="53" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"><defs><linearGradient x1="99.33%" y1="41.9%" x2=".66%" y2="58.08%" id="a"><stop stop-color="#FFF" offset="0%"/><stop stop-color="#FFFEFD" offset="29%"/><stop stop-color="#FFFBF5" offset="44%"/><stop stop-color="#FFF5E8" offset="55%"/><stop stop-color="#FEEDD5" offset="65%"/><stop stop-color="#FEE3BC" offset="74%"/><stop stop-color="#FDD79E" offset="82%"/><stop stop-color="#FCC879" offset="90%"/><stop stop-color="#FBB751" offset="97%"/><stop stop-color="#FBB040" offset="99%"/></linearGradient>[...]0-5.9-2.53-5.9-5.83zm2.27-1.16h5.92c-.07-1.96-1.26-2.97-2.67-2.97-1.62 0-2.94 1.1-3.25 2.97zM377.5 34v-1.65h1.74v-7.37c0-.3-.17-.46-.48-.46h-1.37v-1.65h2.51c.95 0 1.41.42 1.41 1.23v.57c0 .35-.07.64-.07.64h.05a4.6 4.6 0 0 1 3.96-2.7c1.78 0 2.88.8 3.25 2.61h.05a4.49 4.49 0 0 1 3.98-2.62c2.46 0 3.63 1.43 3.63 4.27v5.48h1.76V34h-3.9v-6.67c0-1.56-.28-2.79-1.95-2.79-2.1 0-3.28 2.13-3.28 4.33v3.48h1.74V34h-3.87v-6.67c0-1.45-.22-2.79-1.94-2.79-2.11 0-3.34 2.24-3.34 4.42v3.39h1.76V34h-5.64zm21.48-2.4v-1.19h1.87v.73c0 .95 1.32 1.39 2.55 1.39 1.25 0 2.24-.51 2.24-1.43 0-1.13-1.23-1.48-2.77-2.03-1.65-.61-3.48-1.36-3.48-3.39 0-2.2 2.18-3.08 4.12-3.08 1.56 0 3.85.62 3.85 2.25v1.34h-1.87v-.73c0-.68-.88-1.14-1.96-1.14-1.06 0-1.98.44-1.98 1.34 0 1.06 1.23 1.5 2.57 1.96 1.72.57 3.68 1.3 3.68 3.37 0 2.1-1.94 3.27-4.47 3.27-2.02 0-4.35-.9-4.35-2.66z" fill="#6D8592"/></g></svg>
```

For the base64, if you have a "raster" logo, find an online base64 converter or play with base64 converter in some languages like `base64` in Python.

For SVG path, open your SVG with your web navigator and show the source code.

In both methods, you can adjust the size with `width="409" height="53"`.

Comment: Wow. That's pretty cool. Will have to try it out.

Answer (score 3):

Not sure in which version it was introduced, but in 3.16 there is the possibility to specifically embed a file from the image selector dropdown in the layout context menu:

[image: Embed]